# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

While we are try to get the sessionFactory in DAO class below is the error we are getting:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
<com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler> <TieHandler> <createResponse> <null> 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.dao.NfsdxDaoImpl.saveTransaction(NfsdxDaoImpl.java:66)
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.dao.NfsdxDaoImpl.saveData(NfsdxDaoImpl.java:119)
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.businessService.NfsdxBusinessServiceImpl.saveData(NfsdxBusinessServiceImpl.java:31)
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.service.NfsdxServicePortTypeImpl.submitInspectionResultsOperation(NfsdxServicePortTypeImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:120)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:229)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:286)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:295)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at gov.fda.ora.nfsdx.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 65 more
```

POM File : Below is the maven POM we are using to build the applications. We have gone through by putting and changing the versions of jars but it didn't worked out. Please help any one this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>NfsdxApplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>NfsdxWS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Generated POM from JDeveloper for project NfsdxWS</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <outputDirectory>classes/</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdeploy</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-2-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <ojdeploy>
            ${oracleHome}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojdeploy.exe
          </ojdeploy>
          <workspace>
            ${basedir}/../NfsdxApplication.jws
          </workspace>
          <project>
            NfsdxWS
          </project>
          <profile>
            WebServices
          </profile>
          <outputfile>
            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war
          </outputfile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>JAX-WS-Web-Services</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-2-0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Oracle-JDBC</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-2-0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <oracleHome>
      ${env.ORACLE_HOME}
    </oracleHome>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: hibernate-core depends on hibernate-commons-annotations , no need to add in the pom separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have removed the jar hibernate-commons from the pom file, still i am getting same exception.

Comment: check to see if your container is having other versions of hibernate jars

Comment: Yes Jdeveloper is using internally JPA hibernate, I have removed that jar from the lib after that it is working thanks a lot Ravthiru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include hibernate-commons-annotations. Annotations are now included in core.  You most likely have two versions of hibernate on your classpath. Is your app server providing a different version of hibernate?

Comment: Yes Jdeveloper is using internally JPA hibernate, I have removed that jar from the lib after that it is working thanks a lot

Comment: If my answer solved your problem can you please mark it as correct? Thanks.

Comment: Had hibernate 5 mixed with the old annotations dependency. Importing a matching version of `hibernate-core` did the trick

Comment: That was my problem too, Had core 5.5.6 and annotations (Maven), removed annotations and worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case its having 2 dependency which was actually having this mentioned class

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

thus the error thrown in tomcat was saying that it was not able to find the method in that class  **Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider**. but actually it had multiple file with same package or class
even-though the transative dependency is hibernate commons annotation but its same as hibernate annotations.

The method's class, org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider, is available from the following locations:
I guess below text might help to quickly jump to issue. from which I can say its telling to remove multiple dependecy which is transitive in other

> jar:file:/home/ubuntu/tomcat/webapps/api/WEB-INF/lib/**hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar**!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/reflection/JPAMetadataProvider.class
> jar:file:/home/ubuntu/tomcat/webapps/api/WEB-INF/lib/**hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar**!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/reflection/JPAMetadataProvider.class